# can you solve this

Tags: python-3.x

function: -0.1*x**4-0.15*x**3-0.5*x**2-0.25*x+1.2

Use python to accomplish the differential approximation and Taylor expansion in python

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a coding service and it doesn't exist to do your homework for you. What have you tried? What are you stuck on? What concepts are you struggling to understand?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show us your attempt.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting the question right, it would satisfy to write the mathematical expression inside a function.

```
def taylor_expansion(x):
    return 0.1 * x**4 - 0.15 * x**3 - 0.5 * x**2 - 0.25 * x + 1.2
```

Hope it helps! Otherwise kindly clarify the question.